# Speaker sound quality drops after connecting and disconnecting headset

Tags: sound, 17.04, speakers, headset

Once I plug in and then unplug my headset to my laptop (Ubuntu 17.04 on HP Spectre x360 Convertible 15-bl0XX) the sound quality through the speakers drops drastically but is normal through the headset. I was not able to fix it using Sound Setting or `alsamixer`. How can I automatically resume the sound quality while switching between speakers and headset?

I don't think it is relevant, but alongside with this issue, my speakers produced a loud white noise while the headset was plugged in and I was able to fix it by disabling `Auto-Mute Mode` via `alsamixer`.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue on my HP Spectre x360 13" 13-ae000ni? I've discovered that unplugging the headphones while some sound is playing is an effective workaround, but I'm still looking for a better solution.